# How to trim white space using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

XML:

```
<content name="id" type="text">
             6236
            </content>
```

Above is one of the element in my XML. Can someone please tell me how can I remove the whitepace / new line character using XSLT

Expected output:

```
 <content name="id" type="text">6236</content>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `normalize-space()` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-normalize-space) (Example: http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y8U/1)

Comment: @Daniel Haley Thank you! it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normalize-space() function in your select statment.